# Azure CDN vs Direct access from blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have couple of videos that i want to end user to view on my web site. These videos are transcoded to deliver HLS style streaming.

1) Putting these videos in Azure blob, does that make the videos "Progressive download" or would it get streamed?

2) Clients are based in India / Singapore. That means a blob location of Azure in singapore is closest. Does a CDN give me a specific advantage?

3) Does pointing a single CDN to my blob make it accessible to all CDN across the world, or should i configure one for each geography (say for one for US if US customers come to visit my portal).

I know that the questions are not exactly connected but i am sure you can see they are all different varieties of addressing the same problem

Thanks much in advance
VJ

Answer (score 2):

1. Azure Blob supports standard HTTP downloads, so this would work like a standard file download from a web server. To look at specific streaming scenarios, you should take a look at Azure Media Services
2. CDN should make it better. First, CDN may have points of presence in more places than there are Azure datacenters (depending on the CDN provider you use). Secondly, if you get a lot of concurrent users, then CDN provides a level of caching that prevents Azure blob download bandwidth becoming a bottleneck.
3. You should only need one CDN origin location - CDNs typically pull from that one location.

Comment: Thanks @Atul. I am reading at too many places that HLS "Streaming" itself is not supported as Azure CDN is just a wrapper over "Blobs". Ofcourse it caches the data and makes it available at the closest location. But what about Streaming HLS?

Comment: @VJVRR, Azure Storage (or CDN) itself does not directly support HLS, although it is used by other services (e.g., Azure Media Services) as the underlying storage for a streaming solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @Atul->   So i presume that if i transcode HLS, point to a CDN (With azure blob as the base), HLS streaming files even though gets copied to CDN it cannot serve? Is that a correct assumption.